# How to manipulate a numpy array's elements using an array of range (start index, end index) indices?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a simple 1 dimensional NumPy array called `ar1` and another array that shows the range indices (begin index, end index) of `ar1` called `idx`. The structure looks something like this:

```py
ar1 = np.zeros((m*n))   
idx = np.array(
    [[1,10],
     [40,80],
     [100,110]] )
```

Now I want to change the elements in `ar1` using the range indices that I have in `idx`. In another word, I'm looking for an *efficent* way using Numpy functions and tricks to manipulate the `ar1`'s *1 to 10*, *40 to 80* and *100 to 110* elements and for example, set them to number 255.
How can I do it?

Comment: Just do the obvious inefficient way.  Either iterate doing multiple slices, or combine multiple ranges into one list of indices.  The slices differ in size, so there's no magical way to do them all at once.

Comment: Think I would agree with hpaulj that there is no more efficient way to do this than to actually generate all indices.

Comment: @hpaulj Combining different ranges using `np.arange()` was actually the first solution that came to my head but I thought that there should be a more efficient way to do it. That is why I asked the question.

Comment: There isn't a way of doing multiple slices 'all-at-once'.  A slice is a simple regular pattern, expressible with 3 values - start/stop/step.

Answer (score 1):

what about just generating all the desired indices once, would that be slow for you application? Thinking something like:

```
def generate_indices( all_ranges ):
    """Take a list of ranges and explicitly create all indices"""
    indices = []
    for sub_range in all_ranges:
        indices += range( sub_range[0], sub_range[1] ) 
    return np.array( indices )
```

Then you could manipulate as

```
m=n=25
ar1 = np.zeros((m*n))   
idx = np.array(
    [[1,10],
     [40,80],
     [100,110]] )
indices = generate_indices( idx )
ar1[indices] = 255
```

Comment: `indices=np.concatenate([np.arange(i,j) for i,j in all_ranges])` should be better than the repeated `+=`.  `+` is ok for joining a couple of lists, but relatively slow when done repeatedly or for many lists.

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in range(len(idx)):
    ar1[idx[i][0]-1:idx[i][1]].fill(255)
```